# how to send packets first to wifi router form one android phone and then from router to another android phone??

Tags: android, networking, tcp, udp, wifi

i have two android phones and both are connected to the same wifi router and  and both the phones are knowing the ip address of each other and wifi router...I want to send the audio packets from one phone to the router and router must forward that packet to the other phone??

what should be the approach to implement it??

any type of help would be appreciated

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you know the IP address of both phones, using sockets would be an ideal way to communicate

Comment: thanks for replying...will i be able to communicate directly between phones???or as i mention i have to first transfer to router and then router to phone??and which method should i use tcp or udp...as i know udp is fast...i dont have enough knowledge about this..any reference would be good

Comment: sockets are a direct connection so you don't need to know about the router in your app.  tcp is good when you want to hand off information and the receiving app acknowledges receipt and perhaps sends back a response.  udp is good for sending when you don't care if the receiver gets each and every packet but just send.  Lots of games use udp and continually send updates via udp as they are created and it's up to the other players to read them